# I shared a Folder (within a library) with a user and gave them EDIT permission, yet they can't add new sub-folders inside of it. Why not?

Tags: document-library, permissions, folder, access

When user is trying to add sub-folder it gives error:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

Comment: When you check permissions for the user on this folder, does it say the user has contribute rights?

Comment: @jpollar yes: edit and contribute rights

Comment: Please post a screen shot.